# How to refresh a folder using java program in intellij / Eclipse? (Solved)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I am currently working on a Spring Boot project while uploading images the image get created in `resources\static\images` but when I'm trying to display the image it is not showing. After I refresh the folder it get reflected.
Here is my code:

```
// Method for uploading image.
    public void uploadImage(MultipartFile file) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[0];
        try {
            bytes = file.getBytes();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedOutputStream stream = null;
        try {
            stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(
                    "D:\\New Language\\Spring Boot Demo\\employee_details\\src\\main\\resources\\static\\images"
                            + File.separator + file.getOriginalFilename())));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            stream.write(bytes);
            stream.flush();
            stream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


// JSP Code For displaying image.   
    <div class="card-header border-0">
        <img src="/images/${emp.path}" alt="My Image">
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'refresh folder'? Refreshing your browser? In your network tab in the browser, can you see if the image is downloaded again or if it's served from cache?

Comment: @GreyFairer No, I mean refresh folder. In the network tab it's showing **`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()`**. But when I go to the IDE and refresh the folder then the image is showing in the browser.

Comment: Yes, I realized 2 minutes later that the real issue was that you updated src/main/resources instead of target/classes (see my answer below). Did that fix it?

Comment: @GreyFairer Thank you for your answer, but it did not worked for me. It work for me when I create an image folder outside of resources and inside my project.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't change it in the source folder. I'm not 100% sure, but I think IntelliJ will use `.../target/classes/` as classpath, and will copy files there during compile. Spring Boot will load any `/static` folder it finds on the classpath.
So you could overwrite files there instead of under `.../src/main/resources`. That will work until IntelliJ decides to overwrite them during a compile or doing a `mvn clean install`.

Also, if you run the spring boot app standalone, the resources will be inside a jar file, so that's not a good idea to use as dynamic storage.

Better to create a separate folder for dynamic storage, and configure it as follows:

```
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/static/,file:/D:/...
```

Off course, if you update that folder at runtime, it's not really static anymore. Check also https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources

Answer (score 0):

So finally after 3 days I found the solution to this problem.
Since `resources\static\images\` place is about static content and since it is in general a bad idea to save uploaded (dynamic) content inside your application. So I created a folder outside of `resources` folder and put all the uploaded (dynamic) images files.

[image]

Here is how I solved this problem.
Create a new class and try this.

```
@Configuration
public class ResourceWebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("file:images/");
    }
}
```